# How to get the K smallest Products from pairs from two sorted Arrays?

Tags: algorithm

Two sorted arrays are given. We have to find the K smallest products from the pairs from these arrays. I could think of a m*n*logk solution but this solution works even if the arrays are not in sorted order. Can we make use of this sorted order and find a better solution?

I tried using max heap of size k for obtaining the m*n*logk solution.

Input: nums1 = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], nums2 = [-3, -1, 2, 4, 5], k = 3
Output: [-10, -8, -6]
Explanation: -2 * 5, -2 * 4, 2 * -3

Comment: Can you give an example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: In your example, you pair -2 from the first array with 5 and 4 from the second array. Is this correct?

Comment: @Robert yes, that's the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: (I'm surprised not to find *K largest products from two [sets]* on SO, competently answered or not.)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the heap, try to *generate* products in the sorted order.

Imagine an `n*m` grid formed by indices into the respective arrays. At any given point of time the grid is partitioned into the "inspected" and "not yet inspected" parts. We shall keep an invariant, namely that a product of every inspected pair is less than the product of a not inspected. The hard part is to prove that the border separating them has `O(n+m)` pairs; the fact that the arrays are sorted is essential for the proof.

Now, you may test the products along the border, take the minimal, and modify the border accordingly. This operation will take `O(n+m)` time, and would be performed `k` times. An overall complexity is `O(k(n+m)`).

And the final optimization: the above plan recomputes many products along the border over and over again. Representing the border as a sorted map may drive the complexity down to `O(k log(n+m))`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How would taking the minimal border value help? Won't we need to take k minimum each time? And how do we modify the border?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that has O(k min(n, m)) time complexity.

Let A and B be sorted lists of integers, i.e. A = [a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub> a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>m</sub>] with a<sub>i</sub> ≤ a<sub>i+1</sub>, and B = [b<sub>1</sub> b<sub>2</sub> b<sub>3</sub> ... b<sub>n</sub>] with b<sub>i</sub> ≤ b<sub>i+1</sub>.

Assume for now that a<sub>i</sub> ≥ 0 and b<sub>i</sub> ≥ 0. We will show below how to account for negative integers.

Let p = (i j) be a pair, where i and j are the indexes of a<sub>i</sub> and b<sub>j</sub>. Let P be a list of pairs. Set P = [(1 1) (1 2) (1 3) ... (1 n)]. Assume k > 0 (and k ≤ m x n). Let R be the list of the pairs of the k first products. Initialize R = [].

1. Add the first pair p = (i j) of P to R.
2. If R is of size k, terminate.
3. Set p = (i+1 j). While the product of p is greater than the product
   of the next pair q in P, exchange p and q.
4. Go to step 1.

The above algorithm has time complexity O(k n) and works for A and B containing non-negative integers only. Note that if m < n, we can exchange A and B to get a lower bound on the time complexity.

Here is an example that illustrates the algorithm with A = [2 6 13] and B = [1 6 9]. The matrix below shows the product a<sub>i</sub> x b<sub>j</sub> for every (i j).

```
  B   1   6   9
 A  ------------
 2 |  2  12  18
 6 |  6  36  54
13 | 13  78 117
```

This is the initial states of P and R at the start of the alogrithm. We suffix each pair (i j) in P with the value of the product a<sub>i</sub> x b<sub>j</sub>.

```
P = [(1 1):2 (1 2):12 (1 3):18] R = []
```

On the first iteration, `(1 1):2` is added to R, and the first pair in P becomes `(1+1 1)`.

```
R = [(1 1):2]
P = [(2 1):6 (1 2):12 (1 3):18]
```

On the next iteration, `(2 1):6` is added to R, and the first pair in P becomes `(2+1 1)`. Because the product of that pair is greater than the product of the next pair in P, they are exchanged.

```
R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6]
P = [(3 1):13 (1 2):12 (1 3):18] 
P = [(1 2):12 (3 1):13 (1 3):18]
```

Next iteration, similar operations as the previous iteration.

```
R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6 (1 2):12]
P = [(2 2):36 (3 1):13 (1 3):18]
P = [(3 1):13 (1 3):18 (2 2):36]
```

In this iteration, after adding `(3 1):13` to R, the first pair of P becomes `(3+1 1)`, but that pair does not exist. So, it is simply removed from P.

```
R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6 (1 2):12 (3 1):13]
P = [(1 3):18 (2 2):36]
```

Following are all remaining iterations until P is empty.

```
R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6 (1 2):12 (3 1):13 (1 3):18]
P = [(2 3):54 (2 2):36]  
P = [(2 2):36 (2 3):54]

R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6 (1 2):12 (3 1):13 (1 3):18 (2 2):36]
P = [(3 2):78 (2 3):54]  
P = [(2 3):54 (3 2):78]

R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6 (1 2):12 (3 1):13 (1 3):18 (2 2):36 (2 3):54]
P = [(3 3):117 (3 2):78] 
P = [(3 2):78 (3 3):117]

R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6 (1 2):12 (3 1):13 (1 3):18 (2 2):36 (2 3):54 (3 2):78]
P = [(3 3):117]

R = [(1 1):2 (2 1):6 (1 2):12 (3 1):13 (1 3):18 (2 2):36 (2 3):54 (3 2):78 (3 3):117]
P = []
```

Now, if A and B contain both non-negative and negative integers, we can use the above algorithm to solve at most 4 sub-problems concurrently to get the k smallest integers. For this, we define the iterator function F(A, B) that on each call yields the next product in increasing order using the above algorithm. Let A- and A+ be the sublists of A containing its negative and non-negative integers respectively. Same thing for B- and B+. We call our iterator function for the following 4 sub-problems.

```
F(A+, B+)
F(A+, reverse(B-))
F(reverse(A-), B+)
F(reverse(A-), reverse(B-))
```

where reverse(L) returns list L with its elements in reverse order. We iterate over these four iterators choosing the k smallest returned pairs.

Comment: The identification of 4 sub-problems is on spot. In the step-wise presentation of the procedure to follow, I don't see i≠1 in P, and it doesn't help that *n* starts out as the cardinality of B to be used as `next pair n in P` in the procedure.

Comment: @greybeard Good catch! I fixed the typos. Thanks!

Comment: I added a detailed example.

Comment: @greybeard See example, 3rd iteration, product of first pair becomes `(2 2):36` after removing `(1 2):12`.

Comment: @greybeard `(1+1 1) = (2 1)`.

Comment: I don't understood the need and reason to reverse the list, can someone explain?

Also, instead of calling F(A+, reverse(B-)), we can create another function G, that multiply negative list by -1 and evaluate k max elements, and gives answer after multiply the final list with -1, so finally, F(A+,B+), F(A-,B-), G(A+,B-), G(A-,B+) and 4 k-lists

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of @RobertBaron answer in java (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56402474/6460922)

```
public class Main {
      public static PriorityQueue<List<Integer>> res_queue = new PriorityQueue<>(
            (a,b) -> a.get(0)*a.get(1) - (b.get(0)*b.get(1))
        );
    
     public static List<List<Integer>> kSmallestPairs(int[] nums1, int[] nums2, int k) {
         PriorityQueue<int[]> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(
            (a,b) -> a[0]*a[1] - (b[0]*b[1])
        );
         
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(nums1.length == 0 || nums2.length == 0 || k==0){
            return result;
        }
        
        // Adding all the nums1 and nums2 first element to the array 
        for(int i=0; i<nums1.length && i<k; i++){
            queue.offer(new int[]{nums1[i], nums2[0], 0});
        }
        
        while(k-- > 0 && !queue.isEmpty()){
            int[] cur = queue.poll();
            
            List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            tempList.add(cur[0]);
            tempList.add(cur[1]);
            res_queue.add(tempList);
            
            
            if(cur[2] == nums2.length - 1){
                continue;
            }
            
            queue.offer(new int[]{cur[0], nums2[cur[2]+1], cur[2]+1});
        }
        
        return result;
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num1 = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};
        int[] num2 = {-3, -1, 2, 4, 5};
        
        int[] num1_pos = {0, 1, 2};
        int[] num1_neg = {-1, -2};
        int[] num2_pos = { 2, 4, 5};
        int[] num2_neg = {-1, -3};
        
        // F(A+, B+)
        // F(A+, reverse(B-))
        // F(reverse(A-), B+)
        // F(reverse(A-), reverse(B-))  
        
        
        kSmallestPairs(num1_pos, num2_pos, 3);
        kSmallestPairs(num1_pos, num2_neg, 3);
        
        kSmallestPairs(num1_neg, num2_pos, 3);
        kSmallestPairs(num1_neg, num2_neg, 3);
        
        System.out.println(res_queue.poll().toString());
        System.out.println(res_queue.poll().toString());
        System.out.println(res_queue.poll().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. This works for smallest sum but not product.

Answer (score 0):

Solution O(K)

Given two arrays M and N, maintains four pointers

(i, j) --> (first element of M, last element of M)
(k, l) --> (first element of N, last element of N)

Each time check three products (M[i] * N[k], M[i] * N[l], N[k] * M[j] ) and get minimum of these three products

Based on which ever gives minimum value, moves pointer (i++ or k++ or j-- or l--)

```
  def solve(nums1 , nums2 , k):
    
    l1,l2 = 0 , 0
    r1,r2 = len(nums1)-1 , len(nums2)-1
    res =[]
    while(k):
        print(l1 ,r1 )
        print(l2 ,r2)
        m1 , m2, m3 = nums1[l1]*nums2[l2] , nums1[l1]*nums2[r2] , nums1[r1]*nums2[l2]
        temp = min(m1 , m2,m3)
        res.append(temp)
        if temp == m1:
            if nums1[l1]<nums2[l2]:
                l2+=1
            else:
                l1+=1


        elif temp==m2:
            if nums1[l1]<nums2[r2]:
                r2-=1
            else:
                l1+=1
        elif temp ==m3:
            if nums1[r1]>nums2[l2]:
                r1-=1
            else:
                l2+=1
        k-=1
            
            
    return res
```